# how to append string to json value

Tags: javascript, json

Assuming I have a json variable inside a javascript file,

```
{
 A : "a",
 B : "b",
 C : "c"
}
```

now, I have a javascript variable and append the value to the value of the json variable. Somethinhg like this

```
{
 A : "a" + var1,
 B : "b" + var2 ,
 C : "c" + var3
}
```

is it possible??

Comment: I suggest you convert your json string back to an object, and then change the property, and convert it back to json string; otherwise finding a variable and changing right in middle of string could be dangerous

Comment: This is object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Something like below:

```
var obj = { A : "a", B : "b", C : "c" };
obj.A += var1;
obj.B += var2;
obj.C += var3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys` and `forEach`:

```
var obj = {
        A: "a",
        B: "b",
        C: "c"
    },
    vars = [var1, var2, var3];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key, i) {
    obj[key] += vars[i];
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/rMKjm/)